# Out of memory exception for more than 1 lac data

Tags: java

Hi I am facing issue with inserting 1lac data in a table with two columns(Id & Id). Can anybody optimise the code.

```
public class edgeConnection {
static ArrayList al3 = new ArrayList();
static HashSet set=null;
//static HashMap hm = null;
//static int val ;
//Database connection
public static DataSource getMySQLDataSource() throws Exception {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    MysqlDataSource mysqlDS = null;

    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream("D:/Assignments/Sequence/db.properties");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    props.load(fis);
    mysqlDS = new MysqlDataSource();
    mysqlDS.setURL(props.getProperty("MYSQL_DB_URL"));
    mysqlDS.setUser(props.getProperty("MYSQL_DB_USERNAME"));
    mysqlDS.setPassword(props.getProperty("MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD"));
    return mysqlDS;
}

//Adding values to Hashset
private static int addNode(){
    set = new HashSet();
    for(int i=1;i<=10000;i++){/*Change 10000 to 30000*/
        set.add(i);
    }
    return 0;
}
private static int keyNode(int i){
    int counter = 1;
    Iterator it = set.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        int value = (int) it.next();
        if(i==counter)
        {
            //System.out.println("key value returned ::"+value);
            return value;
        }
        counter++;
    }
    return 0;
}
private static String pairGenerator(){ 
    ArrayList numbers1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();   
    Random randomGenerator1 = new Random();
    while (numbers1.size() < 1) 
    {
        int random = randomGenerator1 .nextInt(15);
        if (!numbers1.contains(random)) {
            numbers1.add(random);
        }
    }
    Iterator it1 = numbers1.iterator();
    while(it1.hasNext()){
        return(String.valueOf(it1.next()));
    }
    return null;
}

private static List valueNodes(){
    //Generate no randomly.
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();   
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    String size = pairGenerator();
    int size1= Integer.parseInt(size)+1;
    //System.out.println("the size1 is ::"+size1);
    while (numbers.size() < size1) 
    {
        int random = randomGenerator .nextInt(10000);/*Change 10000 to 50000*/
        if (!numbers.contains(random)) {
            numbers.add(random);
        }
    }
    Iterator it = numbers.iterator();
    al3.clear();

    while(it.hasNext()){
        int listvalue = (int) it.next();
        al3.add(listvalue);

        //System.out.println(it.next());
    }
    //System.out.println(al3);
    return al3;
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    HashMap<Integer, List<String>> hm = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
    addNode(); 
    //System.out.println("size of set is:"+set.size());
    try {
        con = getMySQLDataSource().getConnection();
        List<Integer> valueList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int nodeId;
        for(int i=1;i<=set.size();i++)
        {
            hm.put(keyNode(i), valueNodes());
            Iterator iter = hm.entrySet().iterator();
            while(iter.hasNext())
            {
                Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) iter.next();
                System.out.println(entry.getKey()+"<-->"+" "+entry.getValue());
                nodeId = (int) entry.getKey();
                valueList = (List<Integer>) entry.getValue();
                //System.out.println("size of value list : "+valueList.size());
                for(int j = 0;j<valueList.size();j++)
                {
                    pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into nodes_connection values (?,?)");
                    pst.setInt(1, nodeId);
                    if(valueList.get(j)!=0)
                    {
                        pst.setInt(2,valueList.get(j));
                    }
                    else{
                        int updatedValue = valueList.get(j)+10000;/*Change 10000 to 30000*/
                        pst.setInt(2,updatedValue);
                    }
                    pst.executeUpdate();
                    //System.out.println(j+"record updated..");
                }
                iter.remove();
            }   
        }
        System.out.println("Record successfully added");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try {
            if(rs != null) rs.close();
            if(pst != null) pst.close();
            if(con != null) con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}`
```

I need to remove the arraylist and hashmap. How could i optimise the code so that i wont get any java heap memory exception.

Comment: Do you really need to build this huge structure in memory first? Cannot you calculate it line-by-line?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are inserting so many rows, you should use batch update instead of inserting one row at a time.

```
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into nodes_connection values (?,?)");
 for(int i=1;i<=set.size();i++)
    {
        hm.put(keyNode(i), valueNodes());
        Iterator iter = hm.entrySet().iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext())
        {
            Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) iter.next();
            System.out.println(entry.getKey()+"<-->"+" "+entry.getValue());
            nodeId = (int) entry.getKey();
            valueList = (List<Integer>) entry.getValue();
            //System.out.println("size of value list : "+valueList.size());
            for(int j = 0;j<valueList.size();j++)
            {

                pst.setInt(1, nodeId);
                if(valueList.get(j)!=0)
                {
                    pst.setInt(2,valueList.get(j));
                }
                else{
                    int updatedValue = valueList.get(j)+10000;/*Change 10000 to 30000*/
                    pst.setInt(2,updatedValue);
                }
                pst.addBatch()
                //System.out.println(j+"record updated..");
            }
            iter.remove();
        }   
    }


    pst.executeBatch()
```

You can go [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparedstatement-example-batch-update/) for more info on batch inserts.

Comment: Sounds like that would use up even more memory.

Answer (score 0):

By far and away the easiest thing for you to do is to just [increase the heap size](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jvm-java-increase-heap-size-setting-heap-size-jvm-heap/).

If this is something you're only going to run once, or are playing around, basically anything that isn't production critical or will process HUGE amounts of data, then increasing the heap will give you what you want.

If you do need to keep the memory footprint down you will need to stream your data instead of reading it all into memory.  Looking over your code it seems each line of data has no relation to the rest of the data in the file, so in a pseudo-code way, something like the following would work:

```
For each line in file
    Calculate data to be inserted into database
    Update database
```

You can increase efficiency more by instead of updating the database for every line, doing it in a batch, which would change your pseudo to this:

```
For each line in file
    Calculate data to be inserted into database
    Add update to a JDBC batch
    If batch size > :somelimit
         execute batch
Execute final batch
```